# Integrity error when switching to Nginx/Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, gunicorn

My application lets users post an link using a form, which is then saved into a Postgres database. It works perfectly when I run the Django development server (I submit the form using Ajax, which sends the request to Django).

When I switch to Nginx and Gunicorn, however, I get this error:

500: IntegrityError at /create_article/
null value in column "real_pub_date" violates not-null constraint

Here is my code in the create_article view (Scraper is a helper class to scrape information about the link):

```
    new_article = form.save(commit=False)

            # scape info from URL
            scraper = Scraper(new_article.url)
            new_article.user = request.user
            new_article.image, new_article.image_url = scraper.scrapeImage()
            new_article.title = scraper.scrapeTitle()
            new_article.site_name = scraper.scrapeSitename()
            new_article.description = scraper.scrapeDescr()
            new_article.pub_date = date.today()
            new_article.real_pub_date = timezone.now()
            new_article.save()
```

Why would this function work in the Django development server and not when using Nginx?

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace of the error?

Comment: Also post the entire view function or class. The indentation in the code you have posted has invalid indentation.